# How do I bundle a single dependency with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler

I'm trying to load a new dependency into my rather sizable project, namely Glide.js. There are multiple nested foo.html files on which this dependency must be able to run. Initially, I was going to just put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide"></script>
```

However, I want to use Webpack. I do have a `webpack.config.js` file, and [Glide.js's website](https://glidejs.com/docs/setup/#npm) says I should be able to use Webpack. But it doesn't say how to do it. How do I do what I tried to do early but in Webpack?

I tried putting this in the webpack.config.js file:

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'

new Glide('.glide').mount()
```

and all I get is

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There a thousands of Webpack -  Getting started tutorials out there. Especially on the Webpack website. It is pointless to write another one here. Please ask more specifically after you have setup your project using Webpack.

Comment: there are none that simply and quickly show how to install one single dependency.

Answer (score 0):

first you should understand how Webpack works, checkout the guide:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

`webpack.config.js` is webpack's configuration file and you shouldn't put there your app code.

Move your code:

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'

new Glide('.glide').mount()
```

into one of your bundle entrypoint, ex. `src/index,js`, then you should run webpack to build your assets, and use generated assets in your templates.